# xamarin android MVVMCross click button assign textview

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

i'm a beginner with xamarin android mvvmcross

i have an app who works fine with two activity
in the first activity i have a button when i click on the button i have this

```
 <Button
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".35"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_Green"
        style="@style/button_text_white"
        local:MvxBind="Click StartCommand" />
```

this button launch a second activity
on the second activity i have a edit text and a button

i would like on click on the button add text to the edit text ..but i don't know how to do this ...
is not really clear in my head sorry ...

thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First declare a *EditText* in your layout:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="Text MyText">
</EditText>
```

Notice the Binding of the Text-property to "MyText". You need to add a public property with this name in your ViewModel:

```
class SecondViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private string m_MyText;

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return m_MyText; }
        set
        {
            m_MyText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

As soon as you set the property MyText from within your ViewModel it will update the layout accordingly. It is required to call *RaisePropertyChange* in the setter of the property to tell the layout that there are changes.

Comment: thanks Stefan for your time that's exactly what i want